# How do I run an application I installed using pip?

Tags: python3, pip

Skill level: beginner.

Hello, I just installed Gym Retro using:

```
pip install <directory of wheel>
```

I can't figure out how to run what I've installed using this method. Anybody know how to? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Using: Ubuntu 20.10

Comment: According to Google, you start at https://retro.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html

Comment: After reading the doc link that @user535733 provided, can you at least tell us *what* you're trying to do?